# How does WolframAlpha simplify this trig expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I am trying to understand how WolframAlpha reduces the following trig expression
$$ \frac{\ln \left(\sin \left(\frac{\alpha  x}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\alpha 
   x}{2}\right)\right)}{\alpha }-\frac{\ln \left(\cos \left(\frac{\alpha  x}{2}\right)-\sin
   \left(\frac{\alpha  x}{2}\right)\right)}{\alpha }$$
into
$$\frac{\ln (\tan (\alpha  x)+\sec (\alpha  x))}{\alpha }$$

I tried using TrigExpand, TrigReduce and FullSimplify with no use.

**CODE:**

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[Sec[\[Alpha]*x], x], Assumptions -> {\[Alpha] > 0 && Element[x, Reals]}]
```

Comment: Did you try Assumptions->[Alpha]>0&& x \[Element] Reals?

Comment: @user64494 yes I’ll post the code. It doesn’t work

Comment: The command with the option Assumptions -> \[Alpha] > 0 && x >= 0 && x <= Pi/(4*\[Alpha]) performs (2 ArcTanh[Tan[(x \[Alpha])/2]])/\[Alpha].

Comment: This will get you part way there Simplify[Log[Sin[a x/2]+Cos[a x/2]]/a-Log[Cos[a x/2]-Sin[a x/2]]/a, Sin[a x/2]+Cos[a x/2]>0 && Cos[a x/2]-Sin[a x/2]>0]To finish you probably need to think more about zeros in denominators

Comment: @Bill How does WolframAlpha automatically do this for many different cases?

Comment: This is a forum on Mathematica, not WA. You radically change the content of your question and its head.

Comment: @user64494 Well I am trying to replicate what WolframAlpha does in mathematica. And I decided to add a little more context to my question, that's why I added the WolframAlpha part! If this is not allowed then I can delete my questions and ask it again in the form that it is now.

Comment: If  I were you, I would ask a new question.

Comment: @user64494 Now that it has an answer, it does not seem right to delete it. I'll keep in mind for next times

Comment: Note that `Integrate[Sec[α x], x] /. {x -> 1, α -> 3.}` is different from `Log[Tan[α x] + Sec[α x]]/α /. {x -> 1, α -> 3.}`, so the functions are not the same. If that's not important, maybe `FullSimplify[Integrate[Sec[α x], x], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, Log@*Exp}]` suffice?

Answer (score 3):

May be this can be a start. I can't find method for final transformation yet. May be it needs special rule.

```
ClearAll[x,a,A0,B0];
rep    =  {A0->Sin[a x/2],B0->Cos[a x/2]}
expr   =  Log[A0+B0]-Log[B0-A0] ;
result =  (FullSimplify[Log[Exp[expr]]]/.rep)/a
```

$$
\frac{\log \left(\frac{\sin \left(\frac{a x}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{a x}{2}\right)}{\cos \left(\frac{a x}{2}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{a
   x}{2}\right)}\right)}{a}
$$

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for the answer. I won't accept one yet, since I want to see if other ideas come by.